# ayda con un elemento clone de jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo un problema con un elemento clone de jquery: yo clono el siguiente elemento.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".alergia-boton").click(function(){
    if ($("#id_alergia_paciente").val().length <= 1) {
        return false
    } else {
      $( "#id_alergia_paciente").clone().appendTo( "#contenedor_alergia");
      $('#id_alergia_paciente').val("");
    }
  });

});
```

hasta ahí todo bien porque clono y paso el valor del input que clono mi pregunta es : como hago para recoger los datos cada input clonado e ingresarlos en la base de datos la tabla es alergias y solo tiene campo id, id_paciente y el campo alergias que es en el que guardaría cada clon. les agrade seria mucho si me ayudan con esto ya q llevo dias y no se como hacerlo

CODIGO HTML
este es el input clonado:

```
 <input 
   name="alergia"
   id="id_alergia_paciente"
   placeholder="Ingrese una alergia"
   type="text"
   class="validate alergia">
```

este seria el contenedor donde se clona:

Comment: Podrías poner el html para que quede más claro a que elementos estas haciendo la función?

Comment: No pongas el html como comentario, edita tu pregunta y agregalo ahi.

Comment: Porque quieres hacerlo con `.clone()`? Ya que `.clone()` también clona todos los atributos. Quizás sea mejor hacecerlo generando un nuevo input añadiendo un atributo `name` distinto como `alergia_puesta` y no generaría una cantidad considerable de inputs con el id `id_alergia_paciente` (Ya que un id debería de ser único).

Comment: El como procesar múltiples atributos `name` puedes generar un `name="alergia_puesta[]"` y luego asignar los valores en un campo multivalue de la base de datos

Comment: gracias podrían decirme como hago eso?

Comment: No podemos repducir tu problema sin más datos como: `alergia-boton` o `#id_alergia_paciente` que a nuestro entender podrían ser imágenes o cualquier cosa, favor de poner un [mcve]

Comment: no podrías realizarlo con .append('elemento'), y lo creas con id de forma dinámica?

Comment: Ya que es poco recomendable generar un campo multivaluado. Podrías generar una nueva tabla alergias, que vaya creando una fila por cada alergia y teniendo un `id_paciente` y cuando llege la hora de hacer el `SELECT` llamar a la tabla alergias cogiendo la información de cada paciente

Comment: gracias voy a intentar hacer lo que recomiendan